# how to find the location of a dataset in cloudera

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am getting the below error

```
AnalysisException: INPATH location 'hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/home/cloudera/UNSW_NB15.csv' does not exist.
```

when i put my code as

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/home/cloudera/UNSW_NB15.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE mybigdata_qu
```

Comment: Have you uploaded the file in hdfs using hdfs -dfs -put ... Above_loc

Comment: also do show create table mytab ot see where is this location